# Where can I recycle plastic caps in the US?

Tags: recycling, plastic, plastic-bottles, usa

The city recycling bins in Denver don't allow plastic caps but some other cities do so it is possible to recycle them.  Does anyone have any ideas where or how I could recycle the caps?

Answer (score 2):

Most cities do not want you to put both the plastic bottle and its plastic cap together in the recycling bin. One reason for this is the two items are usually made of different types of plastic material, so they cannot be recycled together. Find out if there is any recycling of plastic caps only in your area. Unfortunately, even after decades of plastic bottle recycling, plastic caps are still not recycled because there is no mechanism to do it and most go into landfill.